# Trying to make a Module. Why is the function undefined?

Tags: javascript

I am just working to better understand annonymous functions and modules in JavaScript.  I am wondering why "test" is undefined?  Here is my HTML and JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>One</p>
    <p>Two</p>
    <p>Three</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
(function (el) {

    function test () {
        this.el = el;
        console.log(this.el);
    };

    return test;

}(document.querySelector('.box')));

(function () {
    new test();
}());
```

Comment: Because it's out of scope, it's only available inside the first IIFE, creating another IIFE just makes another scope / closure ?

Comment: Thanks adeneo.  How could it be brought into scope if I can while still being an IIFE?

Comment: @Mdd - Declare it outside of the first anonymous function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it something like this if you want to be able to access test:

```
var test = (function (el) {

    return function() {
        this.el = el;
        console.log(this.el);
    };
}(document.querySelector('.box')));

(function () {
    new test();
}());
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran!  From the comments I was looking into trying that.  Do you mind if I ask, in this context test is global right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However if you don't want it in global context, you would have to wrap both the functions inside another IIFE!

Comment: Since you mentioned you are learning, this should also work though it may not make any sense for practical purposes`
(function(){
  var test = (function (el) {

    return function() {
        this.el = el;
        console.log(this.el);
    };
}(document.querySelector('.box')));

(function () {
    new test();
}());
})();
`

Comment: Thanks Kiran!  IIFE's, and modules are pretty new to me and so is prototype although I've been reading about that.  I just wanted to start something so I could try using prototype with a module and see how it ties together but I was getting stuck.  I should be good from here I think.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: If you havn't already, read this: `http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/javascript-the-core/` Explains really well how prototypes work.